# NHibernate - Returning an output parameter from a mapped Stored Procedure

Tags: nhibernate, stored-procedures, nhibernate-mapping

I have a Stored Procedure that I have mapped via NHibernate. The Sproc returns both a resultset, and an output paramter, basically a count of the total records followed by the resultset itself. Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[mySproc]
(
    @StartRecord            INT = 1,
    @EndRecord              INT = 10,
    @TotalRecords       INT OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    // Do a count
    SELECT @TotalRecords = COUNT(DISTINCT x.Id)
    FROM Blah ...snip

    // Perform a query with paging
    SELECT
        x.Id,
        x.Column1
    FROM ...some really complex query that uses paging
END
```

I'm implementing paging via a Sproc and thus need to get the total number of records. The query is quite complex with joins across several tables, potentially quite slow, and thus needs the care, fine tuning and optimisation from writing T-SQL directly.

My problem is that I can't get at the OUTPUT parameter in the Sproc (@TotalRecords). I have mapped this Sproc like so:

```
<class name="MyLibrary.SomeClass, MyLibrary">

    <id name="Id" type="Int32" />
    <property name="Column1" type="String" length="50" not-null="false" />

</class>

<sql-query name="mySproc">
    <return class="MyLibrary.SomeClass, MyLibrary">
        <return-property name="Id" column="Id"/>
        <return-property name="Column1" column="Column1"/>
    </return>

    EXEC mySproc
        @StartRecord = :startRecord,
        @EndRecord = :endRecord,
        @TotalRecords = 0

</sql-query>
```

And I can get at the resultset like so:

```
IList<SomeClass> records = Session.GetNamedQuery("mySproc")
    .SetParameter("startRecord", 1, NHibernateUtil.Int32)
    .SetParameter("endRecord", 20, NHibernateUtil.Int32)
    .List<SomeClass>();
```

But how do I get the @TotalRecords output parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it can't be done directly :

- http://osdir.com/ml/nhusers/2010-01/msg00794.html
- http://www.richter-web.info/Wordpress/?p=132

Comment: Aww man, that sucks! I guess I could split it into two Sprocs, or maybe just do the count in LINQ/HQL in code. Although the benefit of keeping the count and query together in one Sproc is that if the WHERE clause changes, you know to change them for both the count & query.

Comment: @matheiu one of these links is already broken. You might want to edit your answer to include some salient info otherwise someone might [Flag it as not-an-answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/should-i-flag-answers-which-contain-only-a-link-as-not-an-answer)