# Calling a PROCEDURE with output parameters

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, odp.net

I've got an ORACLE package which receives few parameters and returns - with some other (output) parameters - a unique value (number).
Here's is the package code:

```
create or replace
PACKAGE BODY           "USP_SHIPMENTS" AS

    PROCEDURE  usp_GetNewShipmentNumber
    (
    pErrorCode OUT NUMBER,
    pMessage OUT VARCHAR2,      
    pCompanyCode IN CHAR,
    pNumber OUT VARCHAR2
    )

    IS

      BEGIN

    pErrorCode := 0;

       UPDATE 
        UTSASHN
       SET 
        UTSASHN.UTSHNCOR = UTSASHN.UTSHNCOR + 1
       WHERE 
        UTSASHN.UTSHCOSC = pCompanyCode AND UTSASHN.UTSHTIPO = 'S***'
    RETURNING 
        CONCAT(TRIM(UTSASHN.UTSHDESC) , TRIM(to_char(UTSASHN.UTSHNCOR, '000000'))) INTO pNumber;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN 
              pErrorCode := SQLCODE;
              ROLLBACK;

    END usp_GetNewShipmentNumber;

END USP_SHIPMENTS;
```

I've been using this package for a long time using ODP.NET and everything has always worked properly.
Now I am developing a new App with nHibernate 3.1.0.4000. 
So far I've been able to map all my entities and execute regular queries. Everything works fine.
I was trying to call this package but I keep on getting errors.

This is the mapping for the PROCEDURE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="BpSpedizioni" namespace="BpSpedizioni.Domain">
    <sql-query name="GetNewShipmentNumber">
        { call USP_SHIPMENTS.usp_GetNewShipmentNumber ( :pErrorCode, :pMessage, :pCompanyCode, :pNumber) }
    </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and this is the call:

```
Session.GetNamedQuery("GetNewShipmentNumber")
      .SetParameter("pErrorCode", "")
      .SetParameter("pMessage", "")
      .SetParameter<string>("pCompanyCode", "HBP00")
      .SetParameter("pNumber", 0)
      .UniqueResult();
```

I've tried with `.UniqueResult()` or `.ExecuteUpdate()` or `.List()` but I can only get exceptions:

```
could not execute query
[ USP_SHIPMENTS.usp_GetNewShipmentNumber ]
  Name:pErrorCode - Value:  Name:pMessage - Value:  Name:pCompanyCode - Value:HBP00  Name:pNumber - Value:0
[SQL: USP_SHIPMENTS.usp_GetNewShipmentNumber]
```

and this is the InnerException:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'USP_GETNEWSHIPMENTNUMBER'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong!
Is there anybody who can help me?

Comment: Well you [can't do it directly with SQL server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138389/nhibernate-returning-an-output-parameter-from-a-mapped-stored-procedure) No reason why oracle would be different, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I know nothing about nhibernate and odp.net, but out parameters might be a problem. Maybe if you rewrite the procedure to a function that will [return a table type](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/plsql/coll/return_table.html) of errorcode, message and number?

Comment: @alfasin: of course I have the HEAD of my package. I haven't put it here cause there's not need to show the signature. Who says who can't have a procedure in your package? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/09_packs.htm . Anyway, you're missing the point. That package works and it is in use, as I said. You should read the question properly. Unless you want to go on checking "errors" in my package.

Comment: @BazzPsychoNut: thanks for your reply. It seems a good idea. As a matter of fact that package has been written long time ago and it doesn't do anything particular so I can easily upgrade to better solutions. Thanks.

Comment: @ConradFrix: thanks for your help. I am sure your solution would have worked but I wanted to dig a little bit into this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @BazzPsychoNut: I've found a solution working with a PROCEDURE. You've put me in the right direction. Thanks. I've tried to invest some more time working with functions but I couldn't go anywhere so I had to give up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to make it work. 
It might not be the best solution but it works.

This is my mapping for the `ORACLE PROCEDURE`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="MyAssembly">
    <sql-query name="GetNewShipmentNumber">
        { call MY_PACKAGE.usp_GetNewShipmentNumber ( :pCompanyCode ) }
    </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and this the `ORACLE PACKAGE`:

**HEADER:**

```
create or replace
PACKAGE           "MY_PACKAGE" AS

    TYPE ReferenceCursor IS REF CURSOR;

    PROCEDURE  usp_GetNewShipmentNumber
        (
        pCursor OUT ReferenceCursor,
        pCompanyCode IN CHAR
        );

END MY_PACKAGE;
```

**BODY:**

```
create or replace
PACKAGE BODY           "MY_PACKAGE" AS

PROCEDURE  usp_GetNewShipmentNumber
    (
        pCursor OUT ReferenceCursor,
        pCompanyCode IN CHAR
    )

IS

    err_code NUMBER := 0;
    err_msg VARCHAR2(200) := '';
    ShipmentNumber VARCHAR2(10);

  BEGIN

   UPDATE 
        UTSASHN
   SET 
        UTSASHN.UTSHNCOR = UTSASHN.UTSHNCOR + 1
   WHERE 
        UTSASHN.UTSHCOSC = pCompanyCode AND UTSASHN.UTSHTIPO = 'S***'
    RETURNING 
        CONCAT(TRIM(UTSASHN.UTSHDESC) , TRIM(to_char(UTSASHN.UTSHNCOR, '000000'))) INTO ShipmentNumber;

    OPEN pCursor FOR
          SELECT ShipmentNumber AS DeliveryNoteNumber, err_code AS ErrorCode, err_msg AS ErrorMessage FROM DUAL;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN 
          err_code := SQLCODE;
          err_msg := substr(SQLERRM, 1, 200);
          ROLLBACK;

    OPEN pCursor FOR
          SELECT '' AS DeliveryNoteNumber, err_code AS ErrorCode, err_msg AS ErrorMessage FROM DUAL;

END usp_GetNewShipmentNumber;

END MY_PACKAGE;
```

As you can see I got rid of the return parameters which, apparently, do not work with nHibernate.
I am returning a `REF CURSOR` instead.

A REF CURSOR must always be the first parameter in a package ([documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html) (17.2.2.1))

> **For Oracle the following rules apply**:
>
> A function must return a result set. The first parameter of a
>   procedure must be an OUT that returns a result set. This is done by
>   using a SYS_REFCURSOR type in Oracle 9 or 10. In Oracle you need to
>   define a REF CURSOR type, see Oracle literature.

Since I want to return a unique result and I am managing a complex type I've created a class:

```
public class NewDeliveryNoteNumber
{
    public string DELIVERYNOTENUMBER { get; set; }
    public decimal ERRORCODE { get; set; }
    public string ERRORMESSAGE { get; set; }
}
```

which will be populated easily like this:

```
using (var tx = Session.BeginTransaction())
    {
    var x = Session.GetNamedQuery("GetNewShipmentNumber")
        .SetParameter<string>("pCompanyCode", "ABC")
        .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<NewDeliveryNoteNumber>())
        .UniqueResult<NewDeliveryNoteNumber>();

    tx.Commit();
    }
```

If someone is interested I've tried to answer another question with some more [infos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9412872/219406).