# Nhibernate Could not Execute Query - Oracle Procedure returning refcursor

Tags: nhibernate

my package contains the following procedure -->

Package body myNewack as
    Procedure DisplayEmployees(Emplist OUT refCursor)
    Is 
     begin
      open Emplist for 
         select EmpId, FirstName, LastName from employee;
     end;
    end myNewPack;

my hbm mapping file contains the following named query -->

```
<sql-query name="mytestsp" callable="true">
 call MYNEWPACK.DISPLAYEMPLOYEES()
</sql-query>
```

and from .net i'm using the following code to call this procedure

```
public IList<NhbHelper.Employee> GetEmployees()
{
  IList<NhbHelper.Employee> myList;
  ISession session = NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession();
  var query= session.GetNamedQuery("mytestsp");
  return query.List<NhbHelper.Employee>();
}
```

Whenever i'm executing this code i'm getting error 
"Could not execute query 
[ call MYNEWPACK.DISPLAYEMPLOYEES()]
[SQL:call MYNEWPACK.DISPLAYEMPLOYEES()]"

Kindly help me fix this issue, how can i execute the oracle procedure that returns refcursor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're missing the return definition in your hbm mapping file.
It should be something like that:

```
<sql-query name="mytestsp" callable="true">
    <return class="NhbHelper.Employee, NhbHelper" />
    call MYNEWPACK.DISPLAYEMPLOYEES()
</sql-query>
```

I struggled with same issue few months ago. I was using PACKAGES and I came up with this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9416382/219406).

If you want to find out more you can read a good [article](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/fluent-nhibernate-oracle-stored-procedure-mapping.aspx) which helped me a lot.

UPDATE:

You can mix [HBM and fluent mappings](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-configuration).

Comment: Hi LeftyX: But I'm not using Fluent NHibernate classes, so is there any other way of doing this, let me know

Comment: @Tarak: I've updated my answer. You can mix HBM and fluent mapping. If  my answer is good enough for you, you can mark it as "asnwered" and even up-vote ;-)